# How to use a for loop in VBA for multiple conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

how do I color the cell/row of a cell of the **first occurrence** that meets my  condition.
The condition is the first occurrence of each week where the item color is "Meat".
[image]

Below is my code

```
Public Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim count As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    
    For i = 1 To 52
        count = 0
        Do While ws.Cells(9 + count, 3).Value <> vbNullString
            If ws.Cells(9 + count, 3).Value = i And _
                ws.Cells(9 + count, 8).Value = "Meat" Then
                
                ws.Cells(9 + count, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
            End If
            
            count = count + 1
        Loop
    Next i
   
End Sub
```

Comment: why you need to do a for cicle with i value?
 and, for every week you will have a different 'first occurrence' string value right? and what you want is a macro that you could load that new 'first occurrence' and run the conditional ?

Comment: Why not use conditional formatting with a COUNTIFS formula? No need for VBA.

Comment: Your picture does not show us the rows and columns. Anyhow, condition of be C cell value to be `i` and H value to be 'Meat' sound strange if you do not show anything about the the C:C column, involved in your iteration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a way to escape the Do While loop once you mark the first occurrence. The loop was just continuing to mark all occurrences because it didn't know to stop after the first.

So, this should accomplish what you were trying to do...

```
Public Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim count As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim bFnd As Boolean
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    
    For i = 1 To 52
        count = 0
        bFnd = False
        Do While ws.Cells(9 + count, 5).Value <> vbNullString
            If ws.Cells(9 + count, 5).Value = i And _
                ws.Cells(9 + count, 8).Value = "Meat" Then
                
                If bFnd = False Then
                    ws.Cells(9 + count, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
                    bFnd = True
                End If
            End If
            
            count = count + 1
        Loop
    Next i
   
End Sub
```

Also be aware that using .ColorIndex may result in different users seeing different colors if they have a different theme set up.  It's usually better to use a fixed color reference like `ws.Cells(9 + count, 6).Interior.Color = 16711680` (which is the specific color of ColorIndex 5 of my system) or `ws.Cells(9 + count, 6).Interior.Color = rgb(0, 0, 255)` using a more familiar RGB scale for pure blue.

Comment: Thanks for your help! That was technically the problem. Sorry for the bad image uploaded also. Contrarily to your assumption, I had two hidden columns before the table. Therefore I was meant to have used
Do While ws.Cells(9 + count, 5).Value <> vbNullString 
If ws.Cells(9 + count, 5).Value = i And _
 ws.Cells(9 + count, 8).Value = "Meat" Then

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification.  I'll edit my response to change the 'item' column back to 8 to reflect the two hidden columns.  That would just leave the addition of the boolean to control changing only the first instance of 'Meat'.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one which includes some additional features that may be helpful while tackling various scenarios.

```
Public Sub Button1_Click()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim count As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim bFnd As Boolean

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    count = 0
    
    For i = 1 To 52

    'This If Loop helps to End Sub when Blank cell is reached in column no. 5
    If ws.Cells(9 + count, 5).Value = "" Then
        End
    End If
        
        Do While ws.Cells(9 + count, 5).Value <> ""
  
                If ws.Cells(9 + count, 5).Value = i And _
                    ws.Cells(9 + count, 8).Value = "Meat" Then
                    
                    ws.Cells(9 + count, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
                    count = count + 1
                    GoTo Here
                End If
                
                count = count + 1
            
                'This If loop helps in going to next i, if in existing Week there is no occurrence of "Meat"
                If ws.Cells(9 + count, 5).Value = i + 1 Then
                    GoTo Here
                End If  
        Loop   'Imp. Note : Please insert "Here:" after this line of code. Useful for exiting Do loop. If Do Loop is not exited then Next i will not be executed
    Next i
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Somehow Stackoverflow doesn't seem to support code line that consists of GoTo line argument, which is "Here:" in this case. Hence I had to comment it out before "Next i". So, "Here:" needs to be inserted before "Next i" as explained in comment towards the end of the code itself.